# With an OpenACC loop, does each thread get private copies of scalars?

Tags: fortran, openacc

I have a pretty simple code fragment:

```
$acc data copy(a(:),b(:))
$acc kernels
$acc loop vector
do i=1,1000
  x = a(i)
  b(i) = sqrt(x)
enddo
$acc end kernels
$acc end data
```

And of course, I could dispense with `x` easily, but this is an example and `x` is the point of my question, which is: Does every thread here get its own copy of `x` automatically, or should I declare it private to keep the various threads from clobbering it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenACC, scalars are firstprivate by default so typically there's no need to put them in a "private" clause.  The only times you really need to use the "private" clause is for arrays or when a scalar "escapes" the compute region, such as being passed by reference to a device routine or it's value is used outside of the compute region.

Comment: Thanks very much!  BTW, do you know of any good documentation on OpenACC?

Comment: http://www.openacc.org/ is the best place to start.  There's a "resources" section at the bottom of the main page that has several useful links.  The "OpenACC Programming and Best Practices Guide" is a good place to start.